# Entity context does not update database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

Somehow my entity data context does not update database..
In .Net framework I did the following:

1. Created entity model like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399739(v=vs.90) with the table = entity named "Level".
2. Added in code new context for this model:

   ```
   Main_dataBaseEntities context;
   //...
   context = new Main_dataBaseEntities;
   ```
3. Added new object of the "Level" entity with Path property:

   ```
   var z = new Level {Path = "zPath"};
   context.Level.AddObject(z);
   ```
4. Saved changes:

   ```
   context.SaveChanges();
   ```

Databases table shows nothing.. How can I add new item ?))

My Entity class created by Entity framework on the base of database is as follows:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[assembly: EdmSchemaAttribute()]
#region EDM Relationship Metadata

[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Terminals_Brokers", "Broker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Broker), "Terminal", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Terminal), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Clients_Terminals", "Terminal", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Terminal), "Client", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Client), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_ClientsTickers_Clients", "Client", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Client), "ClientTicker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.ClientTicker), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Risks_Clients", "Client", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Client), "Risk", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Risk), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_ClientsTickers_Tickers", "Ticker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Ticker), "ClientTicker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.ClientTicker), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Tickers_Currencies", "Currency", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Currency), "Ticker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Ticker), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Levels_Strategies", "Strategy", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Strategy), "Level", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Level), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Levels_Tickers", "Ticker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Ticker), "Level", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Level), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Transactions_Levels", "Level", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Level), "Transaction", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Transaction), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Risks_Strategies", "Strategy", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Strategy), "Risk", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Risk), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Risks_Tickers", "Ticker", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Ticker), "Risk", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Risk), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Transaction_Risk", "Risk", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Risk), "Transaction", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Transaction), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Transactions_Statuses", "Status", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Status), "Transaction", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Transaction), true)]
[assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Terminals_TerminalTypes", "TerminalType", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.TerminalType), "Terminal", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, typeof(trust_manager_v_1._0.Terminal), true)]

#endregion

namespace trust_manager_v_1._0
{
    #region Contexts

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Main_dataBaseEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new Main_dataBaseEntities object using the connection string found in the 'Main_dataBaseEntities' section of the application configuration file.
        /// </summary>
        public Main_dataBaseEntities() : base("name=Main_dataBaseEntities", "Main_dataBaseEntities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new Main_dataBaseEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public Main_dataBaseEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "Main_dataBaseEntities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new Main_dataBaseEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public Main_dataBaseEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "Main_dataBaseEntities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Partial Methods

        partial void OnContextCreated();

        #endregion

        #region ObjectSet Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Broker> Broker
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Broker == null))
                {
                    _Broker = base.CreateObjectSet<Broker>("Broker");
                }
                return _Broker;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Broker> _Broker;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Client> Client
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Client == null))
                {
                    _Client = base.CreateObjectSet<Client>("Client");
                }
                return _Client;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Client> _Client;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<ClientTicker> ClientTicker
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_ClientTicker == null))
                {
                    _ClientTicker = base.CreateObjectSet<ClientTicker>("ClientTicker");
                }
                return _ClientTicker;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<ClientTicker> _ClientTicker;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Currency> Currency
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Currency == null))
                {
                    _Currency = base.CreateObjectSet<Currency>("Currency");
                }
                return _Currency;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Currency> _Currency;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Level> Level
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Level == null))
                {
                    _Level = base.CreateObjectSet<Level>("Level");
                }
                return _Level;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Level> _Level;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Risk> Risk
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Risk == null))
                {
                    _Risk = base.CreateObjectSet<Risk>("Risk");
                }
                return _Risk;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Risk> _Risk;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Status> Status
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Status == null))
                {
                    _Status = base.CreateObjectSet<Status>("Status");
                }
                return _Status;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Status> _Status;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Strategy> Strategy
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Strategy == null))
                {
                    _Strategy = base.CreateObjectSet<Strategy>("Strategy");
                }
                return _Strategy;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Strategy> _Strategy;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<sysdiagrams> sysdiagrams
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_sysdiagrams == null))
                {
                    _sysdiagrams = base.CreateObjectSet<sysdiagrams>("sysdiagrams");
                }
                return _sysdiagrams;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<sysdiagrams> _sysdiagrams;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Terminal> Terminal
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Terminal == null))
                {
                    _Terminal = base.CreateObjectSet<Terminal>("Terminal");
                }
                return _Terminal;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Terminal> _Terminal;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<TerminalType> TerminalType
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_TerminalType == null))
                {
                    _TerminalType = base.CreateObjectSet<TerminalType>("TerminalType");
                }
                return _TerminalType;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<TerminalType> _TerminalType;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Ticker> Ticker
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Ticker == null))
                {
                    _Ticker = base.CreateObjectSet<Ticker>("Ticker");
                }
                return _Ticker;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Ticker> _Ticker;

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Transaction> Transaction
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Transaction == null))
                {
                    _Transaction = base.CreateObjectSet<Transaction>("Transaction");
                }
                return _Transaction;
            }
        }
        private ObjectSet<Transaction> _Transaction;

        #endregion
        #region AddTo Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Broker EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToBroker(Broker broker)
        {
            base.AddObject("Broker", broker);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Client EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToClient(Client client)
        {
            base.AddObject("Client", client);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the ClientTicker EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToClientTicker(ClientTicker clientTicker)
        {
            base.AddObject("ClientTicker", clientTicker);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Currency EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToCurrency(Currency currency)
        {
            base.AddObject("Currency", currency);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Level EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToLevel(Level level)
        {
            base.AddObject("Level", level);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Risk EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToRisk(Risk risk)
        {
            base.AddObject("Risk", risk);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Status EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToStatus(Status status)
        {
            base.AddObject("Status", status);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Strategy EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToStrategy(Strategy strategy)
        {
            base.AddObject("Strategy", strategy);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the sysdiagrams EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddTosysdiagrams(sysdiagrams sysdiagrams)
        {
            base.AddObject("sysdiagrams", sysdiagrams);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Terminal EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToTerminal(Terminal terminal)
        {
            base.AddObject("Terminal", terminal);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the TerminalType EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToTerminalType(TerminalType terminalType)
        {
            base.AddObject("TerminalType", terminalType);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Ticker EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToTicker(Ticker ticker)
        {
            base.AddObject("Ticker", ticker);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Transaction EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToTransaction(Transaction transaction)
        {
            base.AddObject("Transaction", transaction);
        }

        #endregion
    }


    #endregion

    #region Entities

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Main_dataBaseModel", Name="Broker")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class Broker : EntityObject
    {
        #region Factory Method

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Broker object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Initial value of the ID property.</param>
        public static Broker CreateBroker(global::System.Guid id)
        {
            Broker broker = new Broker();
            broker.ID = id;
            return broker;
        }

        #endregion
        #region Primitive Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.Guid ID
        {
            get
            {
                return _ID;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_ID != value)
                {
                    OnIDChanging(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanging("ID");
                    _ID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanged("ID");
                    OnIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private global::System.Guid _ID;
        partial void OnIDChanging(global::System.Guid value);
        partial void OnIDChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                OnNameChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
                _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
                OnNameChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Name;
        partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnNameChanged();

        #endregion

        #region Navigation Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("Main_dataBaseModel", "FK_Terminals_Brokers", "Terminal")]
        public EntityCollection<Terminal> Terminal
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Terminal>("Main_dataBaseModel.FK_Terminals_Brokers", "Terminal");
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Terminal>("Main_dataBaseModel.FK_Terminals_Brokers", "Terminal", value);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Main_dataBaseModel", Name="Client")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class Client : EntityObject
    {
        #region Factory Method

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Client object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Initial value of the ID property.</param>
        public static Client CreateClient(global::System.Guid id)
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.ID = id;
            return client;
        }

        #endregion
        #region Primitive Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.Guid ID
        {
            get
            {
                return _ID;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_ID != value)
                {
                    OnIDChanging(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanging("ID");
                    _ID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanged("ID");
                    OnIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private global::System.Guid _ID;
        partial void OnIDChanging(global::System.Guid value);
        partial void OnIDChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                OnNameChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
                _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
                OnNameChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Name;
        partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnNameChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Account
        {
            get
            {
                return _Account;
            }
            set
            {
                OnAccountChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Account");
                _Account = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Account");
                OnAccountChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Account;
        partial void OnAccountChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnAccountChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Comment
        {
            get
            {
                return _Comment;
            }
            set
            {
                OnCommentChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Comment");
                _Comment = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Comment");
                OnCommentChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Comment;
        partial void OnCommentChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnCommentChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Nullable<global::System.Single> Assets
        {
            get
            {
                return _Assets;
            }
            set
            {
                OnAssetsChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Assets");
                _Assets = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Assets");
                OnAssetsChanged();
            }
        }
        private Nullable<global::System.Single> _Assets;
        partial void OnAssetsChanging(Nullable<global::System.Single> value);
        partial void OnAssetsChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String Virtual_Assets
        {
            get
            {
                return _Virtual_Assets;
            }
            set
            {
                OnVirtual_AssetsChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Virtual_Assets");
                _Virtual_Assets = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Virtual_Assets");
                OnVirtual_AssetsChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.String _Virtual_Assets;
        partial void OnVirtual_AssetsChanging(global::System.String value);
        partial void OnVirtual_AssetsChanged();

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttri
```

Comment: From personal experience I would use the Database first approach.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I would also recommend using "using" block for context: using(var context = new Main_dataBaseEntities()){ //your code }

Comment: Could you please add your POCO class

Comment: fenix2222, thanks, using block did not help..

Comment: Jorge, infortunately can post here only class start due to its size:

Comment: /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Main_dataBaseModel", Name="Level")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class Level : EntityObject
    {
        #region Factory Method
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Level object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Initial value of the ID property.</param>
        public static Level CreateLevel(global::System.Guid id)
        {
///...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
context.Levels.Add(z);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If that does not work, wrap an exception handler around the above operations and catch what exceptions are thrown.

So the full code will be:

```
using(var context = new Main_dataBaseEntities())
{
  try
  { 
      var z = new Level {Path = "zPath"};
      context.Levels.Add(z);
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      //View or handle exception here
  }      
}
```

You should replace Exception above with a more specific exception in production code but it will suffice here to see what is causing your problem.

Comment: When I type:
 context.Levels.Add(z);
The debugger says: "Cannot resolve symbole 'Add'"...
And refuse to compile..
So Level entity accepts only AddObject method..

Comment: What exception/s get thrown when you replace the code in my examples's try block with your code from point 3 (context.Level.AddObject(z);)?

Comment: What version of EF are you using and what is the entire definition of your Level class?

Answer (score 0):

The [savechanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb336792.aspx) methode returns the number of objects in an Added, Modified, or Deleted state, try to debug and see what you get as a return value and if any exceptions are thrown. Personally i prefer the Database first approach.

```
int num = context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks.. No exceptions.. from your code int num == 1 exactly as number of changes made :)
I use database first approach, Entity framework automatically created class listed in question above on the base of my database